# Downvoting question that isn’t closed

Tags: discussion, downvotes, downvote-reason

I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74243880/can-i-create-custom-ec2-hardware).

It wasn’t closed and it got a great answer in response. However, it was downvoted. I generally prefer a good reception to my questions.

I read the main reason to downvote on Stack Overflow is “doesn’t show enough research effort”, “is not clear”, or “is not useful”.

But it’s very well-known that simple questions like “How do I do a multi-line comment in Python?” or “How do I unimport a module in Python?” can get hundreds of upvotes, because they provide public reference. Some of these answers are easy to find in the documentation, but I thought the SO community had decided there’s nothing to be against about about easy but useful questions.

I am starting to wonder if “Doesn’t show enough research effort” needs an update. I actually think a strong case can be made that it isn’t upheld consistently. I feel like it came from a past culture where people were less affirming about the value of a question-answer compendium site. They cared about efficiency, and they thought answering unnecessary questions was a hassle. But now, I don’t see the value of this criterion anymore. It might actually have an unintended effect where instead of helping everybody find the site good, it’s sort of like “studying for the test” in the sense that some people may only try to “show research” because they know it gets them more approval, but the end result is the same, they are still asking the same question. Whereas, someone may have done research, but they don’t feel a need to “show” it in the question. It isn’t intrinsically useful. It’s just for show. It feels like this criteria is less about practical outcome and almost moralizing. It’s like people praise the good question-askers who show every resource and link they consulted before asking their question, like they have such a great work ethic. But given the nature of the site currently, it really shouldn’t be seen as relevant. The only reason supplementary research is good is when it makes the question clearer, what it is they’re trying to do.

“Useful” also strikes me as conceptually unclear and possibly self-inconsistent. The question I posted (above) strikes me as extremely useful. I am relatively new to cloud computing. I tried googling it and wasn’t getting good keyword matches - keyword burial and Google prediction was giving me lots of stuff it assumed (incorrectly) I probably was looking for. My question is clear and useful to me, and it got a clear and useful answer.

I am pretty sure - as is too often the case in certain programming subcultures - there is sometimes this pretty harsh community culture that is not patient with beginners. It seems like an emotionally short-sighted venting of casual frustration, anonymously online, when someone extremely experienced sees an easy question from a beginner and tramples on it as “lazy”. It’s actually not true and it’s unfair. (A more personal subjective viewpoint I would add is that a genuinely neutral, impartial, and effective information resource has zero business making character judgments of any kind on the participants. Your doctor doesn’t chide you for being lazy. They just dispense medical treatment.)

So I think a problem is that “useful” has a level of subjectivity and I don’t think the real intended site purpose is for experts to tell beginners that their questions aren’t useful.

Does anyone else think my question above is completely valid and if so, can we try to specify some aspect of voting or moderation to not downvote questions based on conceptually possibly imperfect principles?

Comment: But your question doesn't show research effort. *When I google this question, I see results about creating an EC2 instance, which is not the same as creating an instance type.* What the heck did you Google and what links did you click and follow to find the information to reach that conclusion.  Stating *I googled a lot* isn't showing **the results** of your research effort.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: It might be a useful question if you could add under what condition/architecture you have code that has specific hardware component requirements and still needs to be hosted in the cloud. Normally I would expect our software stack to compensate / adapt for the several hardware configs your software might encounter in the wild. Why doesn't that work for your case?

Comment: The question is clearly off topic. It is about the **services provided by a tech company** - not about writing code. It's bad enough that we allow certain questions about IDEs - this is several more degrees removed from the actual work of programming.

Comment: "Your doctor doesn’t chide you for being lazy. They just dispense medical treatment." If the reason they *need* medical treatment in the first place is because they're not exercising (i.e. "lazy"), it's perfectly valid for the doctor to tell them they need to start exercising. Does that count as "chiding"? Because I don't see it as any different than someone here on Stack Exchange politely pointing out that a question can be answered with the right use of Google-Fu.

Comment: "I generally prefer a good reception to my questions" - I don't think anyone posts questions with the intent on seeming them downvoted :) Not even trolls, they have different purposes.

Comment: usefulness is determined over time, highly upvoted simple questions don't often become highly upvoted questions overnight.

Answer (score 8):

It's actually a common misconception that you have to show what you tried in the question. A question needs to be answerable, which means that sometimes it might require a code sample, but that isn't always the case. Sometimes putting less information into the question is actually better as long as the information you include is enough to be able to answer the question.

The tooltip is talking about research effort! A question that doesn't show research effort is a question that if you take the title and google it, the first result you get is a perfect duplicate. Lack of research effort means that the poster didn't bother to check whether this question has already been asked or not. Of course, this doesn't mean that every duplicate question deserves a downvote. Sometimes a question is worded differently and only an expert knows that an answer to it already exists on the site. This makes it a helpful duplicate.

Downvoting isn't the same as voting to close. A question can have any score, positive or negative, regardless of its closure status.